# overriding handle_exception() in webapp.requesthandler

Tags: python, google-app-engine

**EDIT: Solved, the error wasn't there.**

I'm overriding the method `handle_exception of webapp2.RequestHandler.

Here's my code

```
class SocialAjaxHandler(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def dispatch(self):
    # Get a session store for this request.
        try:
            webapp.RequestHandler.dispatch(self)
        finally:
            pass

    def handle_exception(self,exception,debug_mode=False):

        if type(exception).__name__== FloodControlException.__name__:
           response = {'response':'flooderror'}
           json = simplejson.dumps(response)
           self.response.headers.add_header('content-type', 'application/json', charset='utf-8')
           self.response.out.write(json)
           return
        else:
            super(SocialAjaxHandler,self).handle_exception(exception,debug_mode)      

    def success(self):
        response = {'response':'success'}
        json = simplejson.dumps(response)
        self.response.headers.add_header('content-type', 'application/json', charset='utf-8')
        self.response.out.write(json)
```

What i need is that in the `else` section, it just tell the program to do what it would have done with the original function but this doesn't seem to work.

When an exception different from `FloodControlError` is raised it gives me this error:

> File "C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\ext\ndb\key.py", line
>   602, in _ConstructReference
>       raise TypeError('Cannot construct Key reference from incompatible keyword ' TypeError: Cannot construct Key reference from incompatible
>   keyword arguments.

Comment: the error is occuring somewhere in the `SocialAjaxHandler` class, where you're constructing a key. Could you paste the code of that class here?

Comment: there's nothing much more than that and it gives me this error only when an exception is raised. Anyway i edit the OP.

Comment: cna you read through your stack trace and see where you're constructing a datastore key? From the snippet of your stack trace, I can only see that the constructor of an ndb key is complaining.

Comment: i found the error this way, thank you

Comment: then you should answer your own question, and accept your answer. This way, people with the same problem finding your question later down the road, will know what could be the problem.